# Add Request Variable from Client to NodeJS Server for MiddleWare Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to use routes to help server pages from a nodejs server based on a user being logged in. I am trying to take the login session details from the client side, and pass them back to the NodeJS server to be used in a middleware function for checking authentication.

How do I go about adding a variable to a request for a NodeJS route from the client side?

middleware.js

```
function loginRequired(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.user) {
    return res.status(401).render("unauthenticated");
  }
  next();
}
module.exports = { loginRequired };
```

server.js

```
app.use("/dashboard", middleware.loginRequired, mainPage);
```

The desired result would be, user clicks "Login", some variables are sent back, as well as the request to that route, the variables (i.e req.user) are used to check authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the variables in cookies, and use [cookie parser](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html), before your middleware. It provides parsed cookies.

For example, you can send a `User` variable in cookie, and then in your middleware use `req.cookies` which will contain your `User` variable.

Alternatively, you can send data in a `POST` request and use `body-parser` to do the same thing. But for authentication purpose, you should use `cookies`.